# Column-based colormap with matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to convert my input and output vectors into an array and plot with colormap which works fine. See example below:

```
x = np.round(np.array([-1, 0,     1,  2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]))
y = np.round(np.array([-1, 1.2, -3.1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]))

xrange = np.arange(np.min(x),np.max(x) + 1)
yrange = np.arange(np.min(y),np.max(y) + 1)
a = np.zeros((len(yrange), len(xrange)))
for i in range(len(x)):
    a[yrange == y[i],xrange == x[i]] = a[yrange == y[i],xrange == x[i]] + 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(a,cmap='Wistia',origin="lower")
for i in range(len(yrange)):
    for j in range(len(xrange)):
        text = ax.text(j, i, str(int(a[i, j])),
                       ha="center", va="center", color="k")
ax.set(xlabel = 'Input', ylabel = 'Output')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

The only problem is that I like to have a column-based colormap.
Meaning that for example in the first column I want **1** to be treated as the highest number and have the same color as **3** in the second column, and this goes for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to convert **a** to DataFrame and use the below function to create a column-wise cmap.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df.style.background_gradient(cmap="Wistia")
```

With this, you can have more control over specific columns as well by using the "subset" parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I please have the codes that do this? I am not familiar with pandas dataframes.

Comment: I am adding it as edit to my current answer

Comment: Thanks, I'd appreciate it. Do I need to do anything to plot? The code runs with no error but there is no plot.